# Limit $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1x\sin^nx\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

I need to find  $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1x\sin^nx\,dx$$
Is integration by parts a good method here? I've tried to do it both ways ($\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2}{2}=x $ and $\frac{d}{dx}(-\cos x)=\sin x $ ) but haven't really got to an end. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

$0 \leq x\sin^{n}x \leq x (\sin 1)^{n}$  so  the integral does not exceed $(\sin 1 )^{n} \int_0^{1} xdx=\frac 1 2 (\sin 1 )^{n}$. The limit is $0$ because $0 <\sin1 <1$.